# Populate a list of cvHistogram pixel by pixel

Tags: c++, c, opencv, image-processing

I have an image, and a function

```
int getRegion(int x,int y)
```

That gives me a unique identifier to which component a pixel belongs to.

```
class Component
{
    int Identifier;
    CvHistogram* hist;
}
```

I want to loop over the whole image and use my getRegion() function to add each pixel's value to the histogram corresponding for it. Has anyone done this? Is it feasible to overload the cvCalcHist() method like that? I am not sure where to start except for going through the OpenCV source code and copying that method with an added conditional.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it would be easier to implement this yourself?  Depending on how you want to bin your histogram, it could be very simple.  For example - if I take a guess and assume that your `getRegion` function returns a single byte integer (i.e. between 0 and 255), it would be reasonably trivial to generate a histogram:

```
int histArray[256] = { 0 };

for (x = 0; x < imageWidth; x++)
  for (y = 0; y < imageHeight; y++)
    histArray[getRegion(x,y)]++;
```

`histArray` would then contain the counts for each value.  If you need something more complicated than this, you should probably give some more detail in your question.

Comment: I already have a class structure depending on CvHistogram*, so I am reluctant to make a new data structure.

Comment: Well, it's arguably not a new data structure, it's just a single array.  The way I read your question it seemed like a simple problem, so you should probably give more details explaining why you need to use `CvHistogram` (are you using any member functions that you don't want to replicate for example?), and any other requirements or caveats.